How to simplify a generic interface by inferring return types based on a single type parameter?
I have the following interface in Java:
public interface MyInterface<A, B, C> {

    A method1();
    B method2();
    C method3();
}

From the type A, I am functionally able to determine the types B and C. For example, we could imagine an enum like the following:
public enum Triplet {
    
    private Class A;
    private Class B;
    private Class C;

    A(A, B, C);
    
    public static Class getAType() {
        return A;
    }
    
    public static Class getBType() {
        return B;
    }

    public static Class getCType() {
        return C;
    }
}

Then, the interface could be declared like this:
public interface MyInterface<Triplet> {    
    Triplet.getAType() method1();
    Triplet.getBType() method2();
    Triplet.getCType() method3();
}

However, Java doesn't allow this. I'm therefore looking for an alternative approach. The goal is to simplify my interface (using only one generic type) and prevent users of the interface from declaring incompatible triplets.

What's the relationship between A and B.

Are you looking for A method2(); and A method3();? It is unclear what the return types of method2() and method3() should be when you don't define them. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.

If you're able to get B from A, then either B is not generic or A would need a generic parameter.

Your example is really challenging. The way you're using Class incorrect, class has a Generic type. You would have interface Triplet<A, B, C> and then interface MyInterface<Triplet<A, B, C>>

Another way to achieve this would be to have B be parameterized. B<A> method2() that way your interface only needs to assign the A

By OOD I think the best way is move this
public interface MyInterface<A, B, C> {
    A method1();
    B method2();
    C method3();
}

to this
public interface MyAInterface { A method1(); }
public interface MyBInterface { B method2(); }
public interface MyCInterface { C method3(); }


Assuming you mean that A, B and C share some common type, you could add the common type asa. type parameter:
public interface MyInterface<X, A extends X, B extends X, C extends X> {
    A method1();
    B method2();
    C method3();
}

Example of usage:
static class MyImpl implements MyInterface<Number, Integer, Long, Float> {

    @Override
    public Integer method1() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Long method2() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Float method3() {
        return null;
    }
}


I see a couple ways this might work to replace the following, and keeping B and C generic.
interface CumberSome<A, B, C>{
    A methodA();
    B methodB();
    C methodC();
}

How does B and C relate to A? One way would be A<B, C> in this case you still need 3 generic parameters, but it is clear B and C are derivative of A.
interface NotMuchBetter<A<B, C>>{
    A<B, C> methodA();
    B methodB();
    C methodC();
}

Maybe Since B and C are derivative of A, they would have their own parameter.
interface ProbablyBetter<A>{
    A methodA();
    B<A> methodB();
    C<A> methodC();
}

From the sounds of it, the NotMuchBetter is the one you want because it is clear B and C are derivative of A.
